# Multiple runs of same jar file has an affect to each other?

Tags: java

I have one jar on my linux machine. Usually the jar runs alone but sometimes I have to start the same jar with different args. Means two instances of the application are running at the same time. The application hits the DB and has also some actions on File system like creating files and folders. 
My Problem is, if both jars are running, the creating of the files and folders on file system have an effect on each other. This means, some folders are saved on the wrong place and so on. Also if both instances of the application have complete different folder structure.

So is it more a problem regarding the JVM or more a programmatic problem?

The call for the start of the jars is `java -jar app.jar`

Comment: It's a programmatic issue, and this seems like an off-topic question for the site.

Comment: Whatever it is you are doing... its to vague for us to help you here. But I am sure there is a better way of doing whatever it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As two instances of same jar run in isolated JVMs, execution of one jar doesn't impact another. As far as filesystem is concerned, you cannot write to the same location by two processes at the same time.

Comment: *As far as filesystem is concerned, you cannot access the same location by two processes at the same time* You can access to the same folder and the same physical file at the same time. What you cannot do is write to the same physical file at the same time from two different applications.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. For sure the application generate files and folders in different locations but before that the applications have a shared temp folder. This could be the problem. I will share some code if I am not able to fix it. Else I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different temp folders for storing intermediate files distinguished by process ID, time stamp, randomly generated numbers (e.g, five to six digits randomly generated and appended to the temp folder name), additional details appended to the temp folder, etc. like **temp_1234, temp_3456** or **temp_for_A, temp_for_B**, etc. which will distinguish intermediate files for different processes/executions and hence they will not overwrite by other processes, and eventually you can delete the intermediate folders after you have saved your results.

I think this solution would help you out with your prob, if I have understood your problem correctly.